# How do I get 5 latest comments (SQL query for SQL Server ) for each user?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this: comment_id, user_id, comment, last_updated.

Comment_id is a key here. Each user may have multiple comments.

How do I get 5 latest comments (SQL query for SQL Server ) for each user?

Output should be similar to the original table, just limit user's comments to 5 most recent for every user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming at least SQL Server 2005 so you can use the window function ([row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)) and the [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;with cteRowNumber as (
    select comment_id, user_id, comment, last_updated, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by user_id order by last_updated desc) as RowNum
        from comments
)
select comment_id, user_id, comment, last_updated
    from cteRowNumber
    where RowNum <= 5
    order by user_id, last_updated desc
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this works fine. Can it be done without ROW_NUMBER(), just with standard SQL syntax?

Comment: You can replace From cteRowNumber with the select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Joe's answer is the best way to do this in SQL Server (at least, I assume it is, I'm not familiar with CTEs).  But here's a solution (not very fast!) using standard SQL:

```
 SELECT * FROM comments c1
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c2 
          WHERE c2.user_id = c1.user_id AND c2.last_updated >= c1.updated) <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In SqlServer 2005, LIMIT is not valid.

Instead, do something like:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Comment WHERE user_id = x ORDER BY comment_id ASC
```

Note that this assumes that comment_id is monotonically increasing, which may not always be a valid assumption for identity fields (if they need to be renumbered for example).  You may want to consider an alternate field, but the basic structure would be the same.

Note that if you were ordering by a date field, you would want to sort in descending order rather than ascending order, e.g.

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Comment WHERE user_id = x ORDER BY last_updated DESC
```

Comment: "for each user" probably means he wants data for *all* users at once, not just for one user.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM table WHERE user_id = x ORDER BY comment_id ASC
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: It will give me the latest comments for 1 user only, right? I need 5 latest comments for EACH user.

Comment: "for each user" probably means he wants data for *all* users at once, not just for one user.

Comment: wouldn;t this return 5 oldest (ASC) comments of **one user**? Shouldn't you use timestamp DESC?

Comment: ah sorry, misread that. Go with Joe Stefenlli's solution then :)

Comment: Not to pile on here, but the presences of the last_updated column indicates that comments can be updated and become "more current" than comments added later but not updates.  Therefore, we cannot use comment_id as a proxy for degree of currency.